# More than one order request at the same time in online shopping

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have a question.
Currently, I'm in the project of online shopping and we will deliver the products via email.
For the scenario where there will be more than one order request from different customer at the same time, may I know how can we handle for that?
I don't have any knowledge on that and still don't have an idea.
Please kindly help me.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I don't understand what you want to solve.You already tagged this question with multithreading, so why not google it first.Then you can narrow down you question scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Java EE application server, you don't have to care about multiple threads, or  you are even not allowed to control them (at least before Java EE 7).

I would propose to read some basic manuals on how to use CDI. CDI beans are managed components living in a defined scope. With the help of them you can define your business logic on handling one request and the container will care about handling and separating multiple of them.

Alternatively, you can use (stateless) EJBs which would provide you an automatic transaction handling. In both cases, you won't have to care about creating and maintaining instances of the request handlers yourself.